# The same Project Name for different Docker Compose services

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have implemented CI in Jenkins. On every commit it build the containers, runs the tests and then stops and destroys the containers.

```
 docker-compose -p project_name build php
 docker-compose -p project_name run --rm php bin/phpunit --group=unit
 docker-compose -p project_name stop
 docker-compose -p project_name down
```

It can happen that I will push one commit and in a minute another one. So the first container will be running when the second one will start.

So, my questions is: will the stop and down operations from the first Jenkins task, stop and destroy the second container that started after the first one?

Shall I use different project name for every Jenkins build, or is it ok to use the same project name for all builds?

thank you

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? You have it set up already so surely you can answer your own question with just a couple of minutes testing it out

Comment: Also, do you need to change the project name for any reason? Otherwise I'm not sure why you would need to change it

Comment: yes I have tested and it run without any error. Both builds are finished successfully! And I am not sure why...in my opinion it should stop all containers that have the same project name

Answer (score 0):

Common situation, to avoid possible collisions, include commit id or any other unique identifier in project name. We use gitlab with following configuration:

```
docker-compose -p "myproject-${CI_JOB_NAME}" ... up --force-recreate  --remove-orphans
```

Comment: yes this is the one way I would go to...I can use Jenkins build number for example.  But what is strange, I have tested it several times with the same project name and all builds finished successfully. I would like to get more deeper info about project name usage